# Toggle postfix on and off

Tags: postfix, failover, filter

There's probably an answer to this already, but I just can't figure out how to search for it correctly.

Situation:

We have a failover situation for two nodes, using `keepalived`, passing a floating IP between them. The main purpose of the nodes is to run `haproxy`. Each node also runs a local `postfix` that is solely used to deliver email from `keepalived` or from `haproxy`, to an actual operator account, relaying through SendGrid to an external mail domain, as it happens. No mail is accepted from any other machine.

All this is working well. Too well; my mailbox is flooded. I would like to suppress mail from the non-active node, and when failover happens, make postfix suddenly start delivering mail.

So here's the idea.

- normal mode: postfix accepts mail on port 25 and relays through Sendgrid.
- silent mode: postfix still accepts mail on port 25, but it drops it on the floor, not relaying it anywhere, not returning failure to the client, not sending a bounce. (Yes, this is terrible behavior for an MTA normally. MTAs shouldn't lie about accepting mail. But this is a restricted situation.)
- How to tell whether I should be in normal or silent mode: a simple script, probably something like `ip addr | grep -q $FLOAT_IP`.

So ... I guess the basic question is how does "silent mode" happen. Is it a totally separate postfix config, and I have to restart postfix with the right config?

Would it be better to set up an [After-Queue Content Filter](http://www.postfix.org/FILTER_README.html)?

Is there some other idea?

Comment: You can also use the `discard` transport, but that needs changing a file or running a command.

Comment: I don't mind running a command, especially if that would be quicker to execute than reloading postfix. How do I do that?

Comment: Would it be something like [this](https://serverfault.com/a/508152/190386)? although that does say "restart postfix"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, after the hint from @sebix to "use the `discard` transport", I have something that seems to be working:

Set up a transport map:

```
# echo >>/etc/postfix/main.cf 'transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport'
```

Set up the default transport map as empty; also set up a file for discard transport

```
# cat </dev/null >/etc/postfix/transport
# cat </dev/null >/etc/postfix/transport.normal
# echo >/etc/postfix/transport.discard '* discard:'
```

A bash script `/usr/local/bin/keepalived_togglemail.sh` that keepalived can invoke to switch postfix on or off:

```
#!/bin/bash

TYPE=$1
NAME=$2
STATE=$3

case $STATE in
        "MASTER") cp /etc/postfix/transport.normal /etc/postfix/transport
                  postmap /etc/postfix/transport
                  /etc/init.d/postfix reload
                  exit 0
                  ;;
        "BACKUP") cp /etc/postfix/transport.discard /etc/postfix/transport
                  postmap /etc/postfix/transport
                  /etc/init.d/postfix reload
                  exit 0
                  ;;
        "FAULT")  echo FAULT
                  exit 0
                  ;;
        *)        echo "unknown state"
                  exit 1
                  ;;
esac
```

And a line in `/etc/keepalived/keepalived.conf` to make it happen. (excerpt):

```
....
vrrp_instance VRRP1 {
     state BACKUP
     interface ens32
     ...
     notify /usr/local/bin/keepalived_togglemail.sh
}
```

Comment: You can simply issue `postconf transport_maps=hash:/etc/postfix/transport`, it does also reload.